# how to post data-value to ajax function on click of anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

On click of anchor tag I am showing bootstrap modal with form inputs. To show modal am using data-target ad "#mymodal" to open modal. when the modal opens I want to post anchor tag data-value attribute i.e, file link to be donwload. Help me somone how we can resolve this.

Below is HTML,

```
<a href="#mymodal" data-value="brochure/Steel-Weighbridge.pdf" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                <img src="images/brochure-swb.jpg" alt="" class="pdfBrdr mb20 img-responsive" />
                <p>Essae Steel Weighbridge</p>
            </a>
```

Modal code,

```
<div id="thanks"><div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="category-modal col-md-4">
                <form class="form-horizontal login" role="form" data-target="#mymodal" method="post" action="process.php">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label  class="col-sm-3 control-label">Username<input type="text" value="" name="name"/></label>
                <!-- <div class="col-sm-9 control-label" style="text-align: left;"><?php echo $username; ?></div> -->
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email<input type="text" value="" name="email"/></label>
                <!-- <div class="col-sm-9 control-label" style="text-align: left;"><?php echo $email; ?></div> -->
              </div>
              <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Jquery code,

```
$(function() {
 $("#submit").click(function(){
    // var href = $('#myModal').data('value');
    // alert(href);
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process.php",
    data: $('form.login').serialize(),
    success: function(msg){
        $("#thanks").html(msg);
        $("#myModal").modal('hide'); 
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("failure");
    }
  });
 });
});
});
```

Comment: you shouldn't use `type="submit"` rather use type="button". Btw, what problem do you face?

Comment: what is the problem with `var href = $('#myModal').data('value');` statement?

Comment: Actually I want to get anchor tag data-value attribute on click anchor tag to modal form.

Comment: @vijayP I have tried like that but is getting value.

Comment: try like `var href = $('#mymodal').data('value');`. In your html; you have id written in small case and jQuery selector are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Set id for anchor tag like,

```
<a href="#mymodal" data-value="brochure/Steel-Weighbridge.pdf" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="showPopup">
```

Then add this in script,You will get data-value in anchorData variable.

```
$('#showPopup').click(function(){
 var anchorData = $(this).attr('data-value');
 $('#hidAnchor').val(anchorData); //You can store it in hidden in form and then you will get that with form serialize.
});
```

Now, Add hidden input element in form,

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidAnchor" id="hidAnchor" />
```

Comment: No it is not working even alert is not happening on click of anchor tag i.e, showPopup